# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized - Azure's OAUTH implementation (WRAP)

Tags: c#, azure, oauth

I have a WCF Rest service that I am trying to integrate with Azure's ACS in order to validate requests from the clients.

I am trying to use one of the tests placed here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674475.aspx#BKMK_1

This is my code :

```
 string wrapUsername = "account@hotmail.com";
                string wrapPassword = "aPass123";

                // request a token from ACS
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.BaseAddress = string.Format("https://glamstsecure.accesscontrol.windows.net");

                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
                values.Add("wrap_name", wrapUsername);
                values.Add("wrap_password", wrapPassword);
                values.Add("wrap_scope", "uri:WindowsLiveID");

                byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("WRAPv0.9/", "POST", values); <- Here i am getting  The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

Scope is supposed to be the authentication authority right?

Answer (score 1):

wrap_scope should be the realm of your relying party application in the ACS portal.

Also, you may want to take a closer look at this solution.  It's intended to be used with service identities that you configure in your ACS namespace.

Comment: Hey thanks Rick, another question, what is Wrap Password? The token provided to me by lets say facebook and then in Id I would have to give the id of the user in facebook?

Comment: The wrap password will be the password you assigned for your user in the service identity.  It is in the ACS portal.  Click on Service Identities and you will see the user name (provided you created one).  Click on the user name and you will see the password.

Answer (score 0):

Ia m runing into the same issue when trying to use GoogleId/password. it works fine for ServiceIdentity. But always throws a 401 error when using anything else. Also, Rick Rainey, Can you please elaborate on why the above code can only be used for ServiceIdentities as specified by you?